# Como remover pacotes instalados com python

Tags: python, linux

baixei um pacote com `wget`, descompactei e acessei a pasta, usei o commando:

```
python setup.py install
```

Ele executou sem erros, mas agora eu não utilizo mais esse programa, qual a forma correta de desinstalar o programa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como pode ser visto [nessa resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1550235/1606920), você precisa remover os arquivos manualmente. Caso você não saiba quais são esses arquivos, você pode usar o parâmetro `--record` durante o setup para listar esses arquivos, como no exemplo a seguir

```
python setup.py install --record files.txt
```

Isso gerará um arquivo `files.txt`, que listará todos os arquivos. Caso você esteja no Windows, basta deletá-los do diretório manualmente. Caso esteja no linux, você pode usar o seguinte comando no shell:

```
cat files.txt | xargs rm -rf
```

Caso você tenha o `pip` instalado, baseado [nessa outra resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797865/1606920), você pode utilizá-lo para tentar desinstalá-lo de forma mais simples. Para isso você pode utilizar o comando:

```
pip freeze
```

Isso listará todos os pacotes que o pip identificou que estão instalados. Caso ele tenha encontrado o pacote que você deseja desinstalar, basta digitar:

```
pip uninstall o.nome.do.pacote.que.voce.quer.remover
```

Se ele solicitar uma confirmação para deletar esses pacotes, significa que tudo correu bem, basta confirmar a desinstalação.

Comment: o primeiro comando deu error: option --record not recognized

Comment: Falou o `install`, vou editar corrigindo a resposta.